# Shopify orders api returns invalid data

Tags: shopify

I'm currently making a request to shopify api like so:
I've tried hitting these end points:

```
orders.json?updated_at_min=2019-07-17T19:00:42-07:00&limit=150
orders.json?created_at_min=2019-07-17T19:00:42-07:00&limit=150
orders.json?updated_at_min=2019-07-17T19:00:42
```

According to the docs found here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order

this is a valid end point call:

```
created_at_min
created_at_max
updated_at_max
```

The results I get back are:

```
+"closed_at": null
    +"created_at": "2019-08-07T19:02:37-07:00"
    +"updated_at": "2019-08-07T19:02:52-07:00"
```

The above is just part of the returned data.  What gives? The created_at_min doesn't work neither does updated_at_min

The docs say the string should be: Iso8601String

Comment: This is anecdotal, but we've noticed that Shopify started ignoring created_at_min on our requests in the past 72 hours. We were doing exactly what you're trying to do, and it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that Shopify just posted that they've fixed:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Orders-gt-created-at-min-ignored/m-p/553667/highlight/true#M36625